# Update Created By field in Document Library using web service

Tags: document-library, web-services, updatelistitems

I am uploading documents to Document Library using copy web service. I need to update read only fields like created, created by, modified, modified by, version,.. I changed the read only property of those fields to false and updated the values, but i can't update for created by and modified by fields. How to do this?

Also i used DWS web service to create new folder in Document Library. Here also i need to update those values. How to achieve this. Is there any similar property like Field Information in DWS web service??

Comment: could you add your code so we can see what might be the problem?

Comment: FieldInformation i1 = new FieldInformation { DisplayName = "Created By", InternalName = "Author", Type = FieldType.User, Value = "userid;#username" }; I am getting no error and content also not updated. Created By field is updated with credential that i used for this web service and not with new user i mentioned here.

Comment: It might be easier to edit your question to include the code (formatted) rather than add using a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet could help you.

```
// add the file  
SPFile file = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFileName, inputStream);  
// get the list item for that file  
SPItem item = file.Item;  
//Set the Created Date
item["Created"] = "2009-02-26 15:00:00";
item.Update();
```

Comment: I am using only web service. I can't use any SharePoint objects here.